# Recoding and then Summing Multiple Columns Using `dplyr`

Tags: r

So I'm working with questionnaire data, where there are a lot of columns that need to be summed for each row to have a score. (i.e., we have rows for each participant and a number of columns that all correspond to different questions on a measure of, e.g., adventurousness.)

```
df <-  data.frame(
    id = paste(c(1:100), "sub", sep=""),
    adventure1a = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure2a = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure3a = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure4b = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure5b = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure6b = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure7a = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure8b = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure9a = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), 
    adventure10b = sample(1:7, 100, replace=T)
)
```

(In my actual dataset, there are considerably more columns that are irrelevant, and also more in the questionnaire side of things. But this should suffice.)

Now I want to do two things:

1. Re-code certain items.
2. After that, sum all of the items.

I could obviously do this in a pretty straightforward way, e.g.:

```
df$adventure1a <- df$adventure1a - 1
```

However, if I'm re-coding half of the items and there are 40 items, this becomes considerably more frustrating. As such, I ended up using select() and colwise() from `dplyr`... But I wonder if there's a better way:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- colwise(function (x) x = x - 1)
df2 <- select(df, ends_with("a")) %>% df2
df3 <- colwise(function (x) x = x - 2)
df3 <- select(df, ends_with("b")) %>% df3
df4 <- cbind(id = df$id, df2, df3)
```

Then I can sum across columns with `apply()` & `select()`:

```
df4$adventurousness <- apply(select(df4, starts_with("adventure")), 1, sum, na.rm=T)
```

This absolutely works. But it seems messier than I would like—so I'm wondering if there are any thoughts on improvements. It's certainly easier than typing out a complicated `sum()` formula, though, and if there was no recoding, the last line on its own would be pretty straightforward with that `select(x, starts_with("y"))`.

Comment: Take a look at `mutate_each()` in dplyr, You can apply a function to multiple (or all columns).

Comment: If all you need is just to sum by condition you could just do `rowSums(cbind(df[grep("a$", names(df))] - 1, df[grep("b$", names(df))] - 2), na.rm = TRUE)` without any packages

Comment: Yes, `mutate_each()` makes a lot of sense. The whole reason I was trying this route was because `grep()` can be so confusing. So while I agree that the base method makes sense, I wanted this route which would be a little clearer in terms of what it's doing.

Maybe skipping apply might be an intermediate, though: `rowSums(select(df4, starts_with("adventure")), na.rm = TRUE)`.